# What is the Inspector Notes section for in IB Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, interface-builder

Under the Xcode IB Inspector there is a section that says NOTES and a check box that says Show With Selection.

Does anyone know what that does?

Comment: Does it show up for any kind of object or only for certain objects? Could you edit your question and include a screenshot of what you’re referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Notes text field in the identity inspector lets you add a note to yourself for a UI element. The text field exists mainly as a convenience for you in Xcode.

The Show With Selection checkbox implies that Xcode shows the notes for the UI element when you select the element in the canvas or object list. But nothing happened for me when I added a test note for a UI element and selected the element. Maybe someone else will come up with a better answer for what the checkbox does.